# How to Start a silverlight application from another silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have silverlight application. What I want is. If my user clicks on Button 1. Then, it should open Application1(Another silverlight application).

I came through this link. But, it is for launching an silverlight application from asp.net page. But, what I want is Silverlight app launched from another silverlight app. 
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/84046/195620.aspx

Note:Both resides in local machine.

**Edit:**
Also, I want that application should be opened in a new browser tab or window.

Both of those app's will reside in my local machine. Not hosted in any server. The location also won't be a constant one. For example. User 'A' can deploy them in C drive. User 'B' can deploy them in D drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a `HyperLinkButton` that points at the new url

```
<HyperLinkButton Content="OpenApp" NavigateUri="http://myapp" TargetName="_blank" />
```

Comment: Both of those silverlight app's resides in my local machine. So, this wouldn't help. :(

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't prevent Stephan's answer to do what you want:

```
<HyperLinkButton Content="OpenApp" NavigateUri="/mypathtomyapp" TargetName="_blank" />
```

where /mypathtoMyApp is an uri to your app relative to the server root (you seem to explain that they are on the same server) NavigateUri can contain a relative or absolute uri.

Supposing that your apps are hosted respectively on the pages SL1.aspx and SL2.aspx located on the server root (the adress bar of your browser contains something like http://localhost/SL1.aspx )

```
<HyperLinkButton Content="OpenApp" NavigateUri="/SL2.aspx" TargetName="_blank" />
```

in the SL1 app will start the SL2 app in a new browser window.